# Photosets fall behind regular pictures and tumblr posts?

Tags: html, tumblr

When I look at my theme my photosets fall behind eachother instead of showing up directly on the page, it seems to happen most with side to side pictures
Four or five posts will show up all in the same place but layered and behind one post. 
This is the photoset code I have and I've tried changing the width but it hasn't done anything

```
{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage} <div class="permalink2">
<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount} notes &infin;</a> <a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo} &infin; </a> <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank">reblog</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
<center>{block:ifnot1column}<div class="photoset_photo" width="250px">{Photoset-250}</div>{/block:ifnot1column}{block:if1column}<div class="photoset_photo" width="400px">{Photoset-400}</div>{/block:if1column}</center>
<p style="text-align: right;">
{/block:Photoset}
```

Comment: We need to see the corresponding css, and it might help to provide a link to your tumblr.

Comment: If your theme has masonry and infinite scroll, they sometimes don't like to co-operate with the photoset iframes. A good alternative is using [PXU's extended photosets](https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset) instead.